# How do you make images fade into each other during a CSS animation?

Tags: css

I have the following code that has an animation of five images, I want there to be a fade in when one picture changes into another. As it is now it is just an abrupt one image after the other, Is there some way to make a gradual fade in?

```css
#MTG
{
    width:225px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid black 2px;
    position:fixed;
    animation-name:MTG;
    animation-duration:15s;
    animation-delay:10s;
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction:alternate;
    transition-duration:5s;
}
@keyframes MTG
{
    0%
    {
        background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/1/)
    }
    25%
    {
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/2/)
    }
    50%
    {
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/3/)
    }
    75%
    {
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/4/)
    }
    100%
    {
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/5/)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>MTG Animation</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>MTG Card animation.</h1>
    <div id="MTG">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one way you can achieve this is  have a parent and multiple images inside it.. and animate opacities of the images

Comment: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cf4a

Comment: your example animates with fade transition for me in safari

Comment: @godblessstrawberry his question is how to keep every image on the screen for a short while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think playing around with the percentages will help you.

```css
#MTG
{
    width:225px;
    height:300px;
    border:solid black 2px;
    position:fixed;
    animation-name:MTG;
    animation-duration:15s;
    /*animation-delay:10s;*/
    animation-timing-function:linear;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction:normal;
   /* transition-duration:5s;*/
}
@keyframes MTG
{
    0%, 15%
    {
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/1/)
    }
    20%, 35%
    {
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/2/)
    }
    40%, 55%
    {
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/3/)
    }
    60%, 75%
    {
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/4/)
    }
    80%, 95%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/5/)
    }
    100%{
        background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/225/300/nature/1/)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>MTG Animation</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>MTG Card animation.</h1>
    <div id="MTG">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```